# PathMatch full not matching the path even when the path is full

Tags: angular, angular-routing

I have route definition like this

```
{
    path: 'kotak',
    pathMatch: 'full',
    resolve: { fundHosueLogo: fundHouseLogoResolver },
    children: [{
        path: 'login',
        component: LoginComponent
    }]
}
```

But it always complain for this full path that it doesn't match to any route

`https://localhost:4200/kotak/login`

It starts working when I remove `pathMatch: 'full'`

But as far as I understand the path is fully matching then why doesn't it work with `pathMatch: 'full'`?

Answer (score 1):

The pathMatch: 'full' property in Angular route configuration ensures that the route matches the whole URL path segment rather than just a part of it. In your case, when you have pathMatch: 'full' set for the parent route 'kotak', it expects the URL to match the specified path exactly without any extra segments.

However, when you navigate to https://localhost:4200/kotak/login, it doesn't match the 'kotak' route exactly because there's an additional segment 'login' after 'kotak'. This is why it complains that the route doesn't match when pathMatch: 'full' is set.

Removing pathMatch: 'full' allows the route to accept additional segments after 'kotak', so https://localhost:4200/kotak/login will match the 'kotak' route followed by the 'login' child route.

If you intend to use pathMatch: 'full', you might want to adjust your route configuration. For instance:

```
{
path: 'kotak',
pathMatch: 'prefix', // Use 'prefix' instead of 'full'
resolve: { fundHosueLogo: fundHouseLogoResolver },
children: [{
    path: 'login',
    component: LoginComponent
}]
```

}

By setting pathMatch: 'prefix', the 'kotak' route will match any URL starting with '/kotak', allowing for additional segments like '/login'. This might align better with your intended URL structure.

Answer (score 0):

According to the docs

> The path-match strategy 'full' matches against the entire URL. It is important to do this when redirecting empty-path routes. Otherwise, because an empty path is a prefix of any URL, the router would apply the redirect even when navigating to the redirect destination, creating an endless loop.

According to my understanding the route should fully match from start to end since your url https://localhost:4200/kotak/login -> has login at the end you are not getting it working, so please refrain from pathmatch full unless it's routes like below.

```
{ path: '**', redirectTo:'login', pathMatch:'full'}
{ path: '', redirectTo:'login', pathMatch:'full'}
```